# Ignore known-hosts security in SSH for some addresses

Tags: ssh

I have a router with a lot of computers on it. It has DHCP, so they are assigned IP addresses by the time they log in.

Because their IPs are shuffled every day, I get a lot of

> WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!

messages from SSH.

Is there any way to tell ssh to ignore the man-in-the-middle security on all addresses in the `192.168.2.*` range but keep the security for everything else?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to solve the problem would be to use names instead of addresses – a hostname always stays the same when the address changes. Some routers have DNS support built in (you could hook `dhcpd` into `bind9` for DNS). Using Avahi for `*.local` names is also easy.

If you don't want that, you can tell SSH to never *store* the keys:

```
Host 192.168.2.*
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

But IMHO that's just lazy. :)