# How to deal with ssh's "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!"?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, openssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ignore known-hosts security in SSH for some addresses](https://superuser.com/questions/317036/ignore-known-hosts-security-in-ssh-for-some-addresses)

I often need to login to multiple remote stations that are just placed to the same static IPs for me. SSH complains about changed keys in this case:

```
$ ssh root@172.1.2.3
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
...
Offending RSA key in /home/vi/.ssh/known_hosts:70
...
```

I usually just run `vim /home/vi/.ssh/known_hosts +70`, `dd wq` and re-run the SSH command.

How to do it simpler?

Requirements:

1. The warning should be displayed, and not like this:

   ```
   The authenticity of host '172.1.2.3 (172.1.2.3)' can't be established.
   ```
2. It is easy to accept the key change.

I expect something like this:

```
$ ssh root@172.1.2.3
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
...
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
82:cd:be:7a:ae:1b:91:2c:23:c1:74:4d:8a:38:10:32.
Change the host key in /home/vi/.ssh/known_hosts (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Changed host key for '172.1.2.3' (RSA) in the list of known hosts.
root@172.1.2.3's password:
```

Simple and differs from usual "The authenticity of host can't be established." message.

Answer (score 1):

For a slight workaround, you can use `ssh-keygen -R ip` to remove the stored key for that IP.

Alternately, you can alias ssh to something like `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` which doesn't complain or ask to verify. Remove the `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` if you are okay with still seeing it and verifying it.